# How to use UISLider to constantly keep updating the value through out the program?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Hi I have been working in Xamarin.ios app where i have declared 2 functions

1. Initialization elements
2. AllUI

Initialization Elements is supposed to initialize the elements during the app initialization and the AllUI part to keep track of other UI Elements like labels etc.

There is a slider called X1 which is supposed to update the value of how the scene is to be displayed and i have initialized a variable in globalscope and asked it update the variable here based on how the slider is moved, the thing i noticed is that the value gets updated like atmost once or none, how do i keep it so that it keeps updating all the time

Comment: it helps a great deal if you actually post the relevant code instead of just vaguely describing it

Comment: sorry i am doing a univ project can't post my code in opensource sites until submission

Comment: you can write a simple sample so we can understand better